# Show Projects to added users in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a user, a project, and project_user table, normally I can show a particular user that created a project only his own projects, from a users project the creator can add other users to the project, right now I'm having an issue making the added user see the projects he/she was added too, I use `Auth()->user->projects` to show a particular logged in user his/her project created, any idea how I can solve this.

Comment: To understand more about your question add your project_user table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could achieve this:

**Schema**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('content');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->string('content');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('project_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('project_id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Model**

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['content'];

    public function ownProjects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }

    public function projectsIamAddedTo()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class);
    }
}
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['content', 'user_id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function addedUsers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller Action**

```
$creator = User::create(['content' => 'hello creator']);
$project = Project::create(['content' => 'hello project', 'user_id' => $creator->id]);

// Create the user to be added
$addedUser = User::create(['content' => 'hello user']);

// Add the user to the project
$project->addedUsers()->attach($addedUser->id);

// Alternatively: 
// $addedUser->projectsIamAddedTo()->attach($project->id);

// return $creator->ownProjects; // Returns the projects owned by the user

return $addedUser->projectsIamAddedTo; // Returns the projects the user was added to
```

So now, `Auth()->user->ownProjects` will show the projects that the current user has created and `Auth()->user->projectsIamAddedTo` will show the projects the current user is added to.

Comment: Thanks buddy, i tried it out the way you mentioned and i was able to see the projects, i was missing the added users relationship, i did it your way and it worked, i am new to laravel ,so be expecting more questions, lol, thaks again

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark if it solves your problem :)